# Поиск подстроки без учёта регистра

Tags: c++

Нужно найти подстроку, в строке wstring, без учёта регистра. ОС - Windows.

```
static void CheckItem( boost::intrusive_ptr<IBaseTreeItem> root, const std::wstring & str, std::vector<boost::intrusive_ptr<IBaseTreeItem>> & res )
{
  boost::intrusive_ptr<IBaseTreeItem> item = root->GetFirstChild();
  while ( item )
  {
    std::wstring name;
    item->GetText( name );
    if ( name.find( str ) != std::wstring::npos ) // здесь нужен поиск подстроки без учёта регистра.
      res.push_back( item );

    CheckItem( item, str, res );

    item = item->GetNextSibling();
  }
}
```

Как можно решить эту задачу?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50709/discussion-on-question-by------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Чтобы сделать быстро:**

перевести строки в строчное представление так

```
std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), ::tolower);
```

и уже потом искать вхождение.

**Чтобы сделать оптимально:**

Воспользуйтесь методом с предикатом из комменатриев под вопросом.

**Нашёл метод - не велосипед:**

```
boost::algorithm::ifind_first
```

Comment: *Воспользуйтесь методом с предикатом из комменатриев под вопросом.* -- да он то же самое делает. Разве что использует верхний регистр в качестве общего, а не нижний. Ваше "быстрое" решение, в теории, должно работать даже быстрее "оптимального", т. к. приводит каждую строку к общему регистру только один раз.